# How can i write more than one string in one line?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use `SaveFileDialog` and `OpenFileDialog` to save our data and reopen it. I use write command for this operation. I save all data in `txt` format but I want to description before data. How can I write?

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(sfd.FileName)))
        {
            write.WriteLine(Sertifikasyon.Text);
            write.WriteLine(ACType.Text);
            write.WriteLine(FlightType.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Malzeme.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Motor.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Kcomp.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Wcrew.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Nseat.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Wbaggage.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Vs.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Vcr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Vltr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Vclmb.Text);
            write.WriteLine(R.Text);
            write.WriteLine(E.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Eclmb.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Ccr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Cltr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Cclmb.Text);
            write.WriteLine(LDcr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(LDltr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(LDclmb.Text);
            write.WriteLine(npcr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(npltr.Text);
            write.WriteLine(npclmb.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Runfuel.Text);
            write.WriteLine(Rresfuel.Text);
            write.Close();
            write.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName)))
        {
            Sertifikasyon.Text = read.ReadLine();
            ACType.Text = read.ReadLine();
            FlightType.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Malzeme.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Motor.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Kcomp.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Wcrew.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Nseat.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Wbaggage.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Vs.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Vcr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Vltr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Vclmb.Text = read.ReadLine();
            R.Text = read.ReadLine();
            E.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Eclmb.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Ccr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Cltr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Cclmb.Text = read.ReadLine();
            LDcr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            LDltr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            LDclmb.Text = read.ReadLine();
            npcr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            npltr.Text = read.ReadLine();
            npclmb.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Runfuel.Text = read.ReadLine();
            Rresfuel.Text = read.ReadLine();                
            read.Close();
            read.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I want the headline before the values for example:

`Crew Weight=82`

Here the txt output.

```
Light Sport Aircraft
Tek Motorlu Pervaneli Uçak
Tip A
Kompozit
Atmosferik Piston Motor
0,866
82
2
10
19,5
51,25
40
30
1100
1
0,3
0,45
0,45
0,45
12
12
12
0,7
0,7
0,7
1
5
```

Comment: You can read the whole file and put it into an string variable. Then write your headline at the begining of your string an rewrite the full file.

Comment: `write.WriteLine(string.Format("Crew Weight={0}", Wcrew.Text));`

Comment: It may be that I did not understand the question correctly, but I think you could simply use the "Write" method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write

Comment: Besides that, you neither need to call `write.Close();` nor `write.Dispose();`, because you already have the `using` block.

Comment: Unless you specifically *require* this format, you'd be FAR better off storing your data in a class and then serialising that to disk as JSON or XML or something.  That's far more portable and less prone to error....

Comment: Or simpler: `write.WriteLine("Crew Weight=" + Wcrew.Text);`

Comment: write.WriteLine(string.Format("\"Crew Weight={0}\"", Wcrew.Text));
Okay this good so how can i read becasue i want the read only value Wcrew.Text

Comment: `Wcrew.Text = read.ReadLine().Split('=')[1].Trim();`

Comment: Thanks for helping i wil try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get rid of `Stream`s and `Writer`s and use [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) instead. *String interpolation* (strings like `$"...{}..."`) will help us to write in desired format:

```
using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()) {
  if (sfd.ShowDialog())
    File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, new String[] {
      $"Sertifikasyon={Sertifikasyon.Text}",
      $"Type={ACType.Text}",
      $"Flight Type={FlightType.Text}",
      ...
      $"Fuel={Rresfuel.Text}"
    });
}
```

Comment: This is work and i can create gab for second column thank you.

Comment: Is there a ReadAllLines method for read txt file like WriteAllLines ?